# How to display nested form error in reactive-form-validators ?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am using `reactive-form-validators`  to validate the forms in my angular app. I am facing an issue while showing the error for nested forms. I tried some examples but no luck with those.

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9m6xza?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) link.

Comment: [Solved now] with the help of https://github.com/rxweb/rxweb/issues/57#issuecomment-448270990

Answer (score 0):

use the `formGroupName` for nested groups

```
<div formGroupName="address">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8msj93?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: your link is not working.  I solved the same on same link